# How do I get the URL returned using ColdFusion

Tags: url, coldfusion

I am accessing a set of websites using variables

```
<cfhttp url="http://website.com/index.php?title=#var1#:#var2#&action=edit##EditPage" method="GET">
```

Some pages do not provide the data I need and instead of #EditPage in the URL show a fragment
edit&redlink=1. I want to treat these pages differently. How do I go about identifying them?

Comment: pls explain what you're asking again, since you said Tyler's answer is not what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

The hash "#" used in URL is used by browsers and not servers.  Typically when a browser sees the hash in the URL it will jump to either an anchor on the page with the same name, or an element with that id.  Exceptions, are when javascript is used to modify the page dynamically based on the hash.

Comment: Sorry I did not make myself clear. I'm calling urls and accessing data from the page. I want to take different action depending on whether or not the fragment redlink appears in the url

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, what you want to do is construct the URL in a separate variable first.  Something like URLtoGet.  Then, you can use cfif to switch on whether that constructed URL contains the fragment you specified.  Look into contains(), find(), and findNoCase() to determine which is the best option for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll check them out